# Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT or Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I plan to create a Windows Phone app which will rely heavily on:

- Speech Recognition
- Text to Speech

I do not care about WP7 backward compatibility. Should I go for a Windows Phone 8 RT app or Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app?

The app will be created from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is going to be abandoned somewhen in the future, even if right now most WP users (70/80%) are still 8.0

Comment: Understood. As the app will be released soon, I will go for Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight to reach most of the users and because the documentation seems to be more mature.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to build a WP 8.1 RT App. This will then enable you to easily migrate your app and create a Universal App by adding a Windows 8.1 Project to it.

In case, you do not wish to create a Windows 8.1 App in the future, then you can also go ahead with Silverlight based app.